# How to vertically center div and first line of text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create 3 columns. First is short one line text, second is small rectangle and last one multiline text which takes remaining width. Small rectangle have to be vertically centered within first line of text. I was trying to use "vertical-align" property and it works fine if third column have only single line of text, but is there is more than one line of text it no longer works.

Here is `jsfiddle` which shows the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/0yhhvhu7/1/

**Edit:** I think I did not describe requirement very clear. I don't want to vertically align all 3 columns. Text in the first column should still be at the top. Small rectangle in second column should still be at the top - but aligned as if it was "-" symbol in the first column text. First line of text in the last column should still be at the top and its baseline should match baseline of text in first column.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use flex boxes for this. A lot of tasks like this have become a lot easier with flexbox.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) and see caniuse for the pretty good [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yhhvhu7/2/) in your case. The key is

```
.content{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

on the container in which you want the alignment to take place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the indicator to be always middle to the text on the right this is a solution.

Here is a [working solution](https://jsfiddle.net/Averlion/0rtLzeg9/) I changed kind a lot to make it work.
First i made the content position to relative

```
.content{
    font-size: 20px;
    position:relative;
}
```

and i changed also the left div

```
.left{
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
}
```

so that it has the same height as the right div.

Now i needed to make the time and indicator align vertical in the middle.
For that i set the top position to 50% and added a margin-top to -11px. That is a posible way to set something in the middle.

```
.time{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-11px
}

.indicator{
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-2px;
    left:50px;
}
```

If you want it to be always fixed to a specific height you can also change the top:50% to a specific value like 10px.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. You just make `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`

```css
.content{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.left {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70px;
}

.right{
    display: table-cell;
    margin-left: 70px;
}

.time{
    display: inline-block;  
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.indicator{
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="left">  
        <div class="time">21:00</div>
        <div class="indicator"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
            <div class="label">Hello World, Hello World, Hello World, Hello World, Hello World, Hello World, Hello World, Hello World, Hello World, Hello World, Hello World,</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried table/table-cell solution but I want first line of the text in the third column to be baseline aligned with the text in the first column.